# Databases and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql, sql-server, svn, visual-studio-2013

I am collaborating on a project with several other people in Visual Studio 2013.  We are using Tortoise SVN to share the project so that we are all working on the same files.  I was in charge of constructing the database, which I did.  But after making the database in the SQL Server Object Explorer under (localdb)\Projects(SQL Server 11.0.3000-THE-DRAGON-DEN\Dragonfett), I can not seem to find the database in the solution folder for the project.

How do I get the database into the project folder?

Answer (score 1):

That is merely a link to a SQL Server database.

If you want the database in the solution folder then you will need some form of project.  SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx) is what you are looking for.  AFAIK this is installed with VS2012 and VS2013.  For VS2010 you will need to install SSDT manually.

Select File->New->Project and in the templates look for SQL Server Database Project under the SQL Server Template group.  SSDT has a great import facility which will let you import the contents of an existing database with no fuss.  SSDT as a project can then be checked into and controlled by SVN.

Other that that, Installing, configuring and using SSDAT is beyond the scope of the question.  I would suggest you do a bit of homework and read up on SSDT and how it works.